# Bootstrap dropdown menu stay open to type

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a bootstrap dropdown menu as following:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="more" class="button_icon">More</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="more">
    <li>
        <input class="btn-block"/>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The dropdown function works fine, however whenever I try to type something on the input field, the menu closes.

Is there a way to force it open while it is within the dropdown menu (such as the input field)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent dropdown event when clicked on input text box. You can achieve this by using `jQuery`. [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt5s3L4s/)

in `input` add class `dropdown-input`

```
<input type="text" class="btn-block dropdown-input"/>
```

and add this script to prevent the event from closing the dropdown when type/click on text box

```
$('.dropdown-input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```